# Kotlin Jetpack Compose Understanding Type in Delegate property

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, delegated-properties

I'm having difficulty to understand **Type** of property when using delegated property. For example, from this Jetpack Compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), it says both things are same.

```
 1. val name: String by helloViewModel.name.observeAsState("")
 2. val nameState: State<String> = helloViewModel.name.observeAsState("")
```

I've gone through the Kotlin Delegated property documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html). For the first example, according to documentation, `val name:String`, when we try to read this `name` property, it will call `getValue()` function on the delegate instance, whose return type would be `String`, not `State<String>`. But how come it is returning `State<String`>, this part I didn't get completely.

Can you point me what I'm missing to understand this logic, or any link to documents/blog post would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val nameState: State<String> = helloViewModel.name.observeAsState("")
val name: String = nameState.value
```

[observeAsState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/livedata/package-summary#observeAsState(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData,kotlin.Any))'s return type is `State<R>`, where R is `String` in this case (since `name` is declared as `LiveData<String>`). At this stage you can retrieve the state's value from [State#value](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/State#value()) property.

---

```
val name: String by helloViewModel.name.observeAsState("")
```

This syntax is pretty similar, the only difference is it declares local variable as delegated property, where the [delegate itself](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(androidx.compose.runtime.State).getValue(kotlin.Any,kotlin.reflect.KProperty)) just returns the `State`'s [value](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/State#value()) property.

The delegate's `getValue` implementation (from Compose's [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/0f99bf184a7ed902e4b8af04d70c48aa2a68e92f:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotState.kt;l=80-86?q=snapshotstate&ss=androidx), note that it just returns the `State`'s value):

```
inline operator fun <T> State<T>.getValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = value
```